# Google Sheets - QUERY function with "count" aggregate and mixed data types

Tags: google-sheets, google-query-language

I'm trying to get the count of non-empty cells in a column of mixed numbers and text in a Google Sheets document using the [`QUERY`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343?hl=en-GB) function, but I'm getting some results I don't understand from the `count` [aggregate function](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage#aggregation-functions) inside the query.

I've reduced my issue to this example to demonstrate the problem (or at least show where my misunderstanding is):

| . | A | B | C | D | E | F |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 | 10 | 10 | 10 | 10 | aa |
| 2 | 20 | 20 | 20 | 20 | bb | bb |
| 3 | 30 | 30 | 30 | cc | cc | cc |
| 4 | 40 | 40 | dd | dd | dd | dd |
| 5 | 50 | ee | ee | ee | ee | ee |
| 6 |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 7 | select count(A) | select count(B) | select count(C) | select count(D) | select count(E) | select count(F) |
| 8 | `=query(A1:A5,A7)` | `=query(B1:B5,B7)` | `=query(C1:C5,C7)` | `=query(D1:D5,D7)` | `=query(E1:E5,E7)` | `=query(F1:F5,F7)` |
| 9 | **5** | **4** | **3** | **5** | **5** | **5** |

This gives me the expected value in cells A9, D9, E9 and F9, but I've got a couple of questions:

- what is going on in columns B and C to cause them to give counts of 4 and 3 respectively?
- how do I modify my function / query to count the number of non-empty cells in the query range regardless of data types?

I know there are other functions like `COUNTA` that could solve this simple case, but my actual scenario is more complicated and is part of a larger `QUERY` function, and it's highlighted to me that the behaviour of `query("... count() ...")` isn't what I expected, so I'm trying to understand that specifically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try below formula-

```
=QUERY(INDEX(TEXT(B1:B5,"@")),"select count(Col1)")
```

`QUERY()` function is auto detecting these columns as numbers so it is excluding text strings.

Comment: Fab, thanks. That works in isolation, but it obviously changes the column's datatype so other functions like ```sum(Col1)``` don't work. I'm not sure there's actually a clean silver-bullet solution, tbh - I'll probably end up using your answer in a separate query and then combine it somehow with my existing query results on a new sheet...

Comment: You can't use `sum()` for text values. Depends on result you are expecting.

Comment: So I've got mixed numeric and text in a single column - I'm trying to get a count of all values, and a sum of the numbers. However, if ```QUERY``` detects the column as numeric per my original question it ignores text in the ```count``` and if I use this answer the ```sum``` fails, so I don't think I can do both in a single query.

Comment: I think you can try `=QUERY({INDEX(TEXT(B1:B5,"@")),B1:B5},"select count(Col1),sum(Col2)")`.

Comment: Ah, nice. Yeah, that works. I'll need to add some more columns to integrate it into my actual sheet, but that definitely solves the problem I was having. If you want to add that to your answer I'll accept that...

Comment: You can accept the answer. Comments are also part of answer.